# Carbon Bianchi Road bike making vibrating/rubbing noise when descending

Tags: noise

My Bianchi Road bike is having a very strange issue, almost every time I am descending especially down a steep hill it starts to make a really loud rubbing/vibrating sort of noise yet as soon as I start peddling the noise stops. But if I stop peddling and continue to descend the noise quickly resumes and doesn’t stop until I pedal again. I’m not sure if anyone has had a similar issue and whether they may be able to diagnose what the problem is.

https://on.soundcloud.com/ovhtPhD3mefP9yXd6

I have attached a link on SoundCloud where I have uploaded the noise that it makes, if anyone can help that would be great thanks.

Comment: Isn’t it just the freewheel mechanism? Can you reproduce it when you suspend the bike in the air (a string around the saddle nose attached to a roof beam works nicely)?

Comment: I'll be the annoying commenter who nitpicks your spelling. But if you like riding your bike it's worth knowing that you will be pedalling not peddling said bike. Unless you want to get rid off it...

Comment: is the issue only present when descending? if so then try replicating the coasting under high speed by turning the crank fast while the bike is suspended then stopping abruptly. if symptoms don't occur then your weight on the bike might be relevant to the problem. (the rear hub axle being loaded and causing the freewheel/hub noise)